# change default "picture no available" icon in Android

Tags: android

I've wrote an app that encrypt/decrypt pictures. When the encrypted image is stored, in the image gallery we can see the "picture no available" icon for this encrypted image. I would like to change this to default icon, but I don't know where is this default stored...

thanks!

EDIT

What I am trying to do now, is with BitMapFactory convert the encripted file to a bitmap. The icon it's not possible to change and EXIF algorithm is not exactly what I want.
With this code I obtain a black bitmap, what I would like to do is to obtain a bitmap from the encripted file that shows colour pixels. Any idea?

```
Bittmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/sdcard/abc.jpg");
Bitmap bm = bitmap.createBitmap(30, 30, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bm.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 30, bos);
bos.toByteArray();

FileOutputStream ft = new FileOutputStream(new File("/sdcard/ab.jpg"));
bos.writeTo(ft);
bos.flush();
ft.flush();
bos.close();
ft.close();
```

Comment: Does the image opens correctly in the gallery? If you can open correctly, it means the headers of photo got changed during the encrypt / decrypt process.

Comment: @Akatosh it's possible to encrypt an image with AES and mantain jpg format?

Comment: You can, but you need to be sure you are encrypting all data, including the headers. If you manage to decrypt well, the headers should be there.

Comment: @Akatosh I can encrypt and decrypt an image maintaining the jpg format, what I want to do is encrypt a jpg without encrypting the headers or add jpg headers to encrypted image to have a preview in the image gallery

Comment: Well, you can check for [EXIF algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format) to extract the header before the encrypting process. I never tried it but it seems like fun.

Answer (score 0):

This is outside of your control. Default Gallery appliaction (and probably 1000 others on Google Play) display their own image when parsing fails the way they want.

Comment: so then, it's possible to change the image to show after it's encrypted in other way?

Comment: Android uses the image to generate the preview, so my guess is no.

Comment: @user2436195 Technically this is possible. If you learned about png internals, there is a header part where you could put your encrypted file and use predefined file for data part. Not very easy, but (I think) doable. I would certainly want to see this if you make it work.

Comment: @MaciejGórski I am trying to different things. One is to add png header to the encrypted file and the other is to avoid picture header on encryption

Answer (score 0):

Since your app encrypts images I guess that you want them all to be viewable only by your app. So why don't you just change the file extension to something other so that the Android Image gallery won't recognize the file as image and try to display it.

Comment: what I want it's to display all the encrypted images with a standard image different than "picture not available"

Comment: I don;t know if this is possible. Android gallery decodes and scales the image to show it as a thumbnail in the grid/list and when you choose it you see the full image. When it cannot decode the image then it displays a default thumbnail, to which I guess you don't have access to.  

Maybe try something more sofisticated. Like adding the data of the thumbnail first. then the data of the encrypted image and make sure these data are split in a way that the android gallery does not take into account the rest of the bits.

Comment: Or maybe save the encrypted image in a different directory and replace it with your thumbnail in the images directory. When your app restores the image, delete the thumbnail and bring back in the images directory the real image.